# Using Tess4J on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ocr, tesseract, native-code

When I use the Tess4J library I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI
```

at runtime.

But I don't get the meaning of this error, nor I am able to resolve it.

My problem is that 2 native dlls have to be loaded by Tess4J but this is out of my hands. I've added the location of the dlls to the build path for each jar.

I noticed, that when I first trigger Tess4J with my client, I get an error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302'
```

but every consecutive call results in the `NoClassDefFoundError`exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case switching from 64-bit Java to 32-bit Java solved the **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302' problem (Tesseract is a 32-bit app)**. Don't forget to put **libtesseract302.dll**, **liblept168.dll** and **tessdata** in **jdk/bin folder**.

Comment: thanks for response, but I already did that. But I am not sure about where to place the files. Copied them into jdk/bin but that didn't help. It works for me as standalone, but I cant' figure out how to use Tess4J on tomcat.

Comment: Found the solution. I had to set the correct JVM in the corresponding Server-setting, not for the project. I accept your answer since it points in the right direction.

Comment: @SatelliteSD I have the same problem as You had. Could You please post instructions how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Configure the JVM as 32 bit for the server and for the application.

Comment: @SatelliteSD I have the same problem please how to Configure the JVM ?